# What indexes, and where, should I create to optimize my view?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-view, sql-optimization

I'm working with really large datasets, with one table being at around 90 million records right now.

I have a view, `LINK`, which joins three tables. It generally looks like...

```sql
SELECT ...
FROM Accounts
LEFT JOIN RunInfo
    ON Accounts.File = RunInfo.File
    AND Accounts.AccountName = RunInfo.Account
LEFT JOIN JobInfo
    ON RunInfo.Machine = JobInfo.Machine
    AND RunInfo.Job = JobInfo.Job
    AND RunInfo.File = JobInfo.File
LEFT JOIN Barcodes
    ON RunInfo.RunInstance = Barcodes.RunInstance
    AND RunInfo.File = Barcodes.File
    AND RunInfo.Machine = Barcodes.Machine
    AND RunInfo.Job = Barcodes.Job
```

I currently have a single nonclustered index in `Barcodes.barcode` (this is the largest table in the view by a significant margin), as when I run queries that involve joining a table to this massive view, the join always occurs on `NewTable.barcode = LINK.barcode`.

I'm not particularly knowledgeable on the art of optimization, which is why some operations can against this view can take 15 minutes or more.

What indexes should I be creating, and where, to optimize this?

Comment: Look at the query plans for your expensive queries.  They will contain index recommendations.

Comment: This question should be updated with full code and table schemas and current execution plans. Otherwise it seems too vague to speculate about.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft looking into that now! thank you for the advice